# regex expression for extract amounts

Tags: python, regex

I have a `"7 9/16 x 9 1/2 in. (19.21 x 24.13 cm) (image)"` amounts, i want to extract `cm` amount as a height and width

expected output should be `19.21 and 24.13`

i have tried `re.findall('\(.*?cm\)',value)`, but this will return list and again i have to split it with `x` and remove `cm` from string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`([\d.]+)\s*x\s*([\d.]+)(?= cm)`

See Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2NwggV/3)

Python3 Code:

```
import re

value = "7 9/16 x 9 1/2 in. (19.21 x 24.13 cm) (image)"

size = list(re.findall('([\d.]+)\s*x\s*([\d.]+)(?= cm)', value)[0])
print(size[0] + " and " + size[1])
```

Output:

`19.21 and 24.13`

Comment: Or 
((\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*x\s*(\d+(\.\d+)?)\scm)

Comment: i have to try it with `re.match` ? and then result.group(1) ?

Comment: @Alireza, only one thing in this is space in both values

Comment: The two values are in group 2 and group 4, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you intended to match the value between the parenthesis. You might also make the match for the amounts a bit more specific matching 1 or more digits with an optional decimal part `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

```
\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?) x (\d+(?:\.\d+)?) cm\)
```

**Explanation**

- `\(` Match `(`
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `x`  Match literally
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `cm\)` Match a space and `cm)`

Example code

```
import re

value = "7 9/16 x 9 1/2 in. (19.21 x 24.13 cm) (image)"
pattern = r"\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?) x (\d+(?:\.\d+)?) cm\)"

for x in re.findall(pattern, value):
    print (f"{x[0]} and {x[1]}")
```

Output

```
19.21 and 24.13
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jgnIXH)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x = "7 9/16 x 9 1/2 in. (19.21 x 24.13 cm) (image)"

import re
y = re.find_all((?:\()(.*)(?:x)(.*)(?:cm\)), x)
```

**Output:**

```
['19.21', '24.13']
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope the regex helps you:
`\(([\d.]+)(?:[^\d.]+)([\d.]+).+cm\)`

In python source:

```
import re

txt = "7 9/16 x 9 1/2 in. (19.21     x 24.13 cm) (image)"
x = re.findall("\(([\d.]+)(?:[^\d.]+)([\d.]+).+cm\)", txt)
print(x)
for item in x:
    print(item[0] + ' and ' + item[1])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
19.21 and 24.13
```